# jquery modal window with iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I have a website where I open jquery modal window with iframe. right if user click the content of the iframe within modal it redirects to the other page but within iframe.

is there any way to add listener or something if user click anything within iframe get clicked url and redirect parent page?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a listener but if the pages are on the same domain you will have access to window.parent.location which should change the location of the parent page.